# running a large number of "counting QL" on a noSQL "GAE" data store

Tags: java, performance, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

before we start let me give you some information about our environment:

- it is written fully in Java/J2EE.
- it is developed to be deployed on GAE "Google App Engine"
- its GUI is developed by GWT.
- our problem is in a core development issue.

Here is my problem,

- i am building a web application where users "online" can search for listings in this website.
- first please open the web site careerbuilder.com and search for any keyword e.g. "Accounting".
- a page will be opened , [Narrow Search] has a way to allow you go to your target job easier "lets call this a filter" ,lots of jobs down there.
- search filter includes sub-filters [Category , Company , City , State ].
- each sub-filter has many cases or options. like for "State has (California ,Iowa , Kansas , ...etc)" beside each one of them is the number of jobs that matches your current filter/sub-filter selection. you will find it between brackets i.e. (23)

Now we want to allow this filter functionality and we want to make it fast. 
making a count query for each sub-filter option is going to be an effective idea.

kindly keep in mind that:

- users can add/remove listing.
- also listings can expire.
- number of sub-filters are higher for us "can reach 20".
- each sub-filter has between 2 and 200 options.

we are searching for the best practice or a suggestion of an algorithm or whatever to solve this problem.

here are 2 options we have reached so far:

1.building a statistics table to save these results in it, then update it each time listings number is changed , also keep a nightly background job to recalculate results. and we can show number of results directly from this table.

2.build a tree data structure to be loaded on memory and saved in a table each time it is updated. this tree contains the resulting numbers of listings in each option of sub-filters.

even though i still think this is not enough !!! 
can anyone suggest a better idea? 
all comments, questions, suggestions are very welcomed.

Regards

Mohammad S.

Answer (score 1):

Have you noticed how Google applications rarely give exact counts on anything? Especially, when using filters? You always get these guesstimates, like 'more than 1000' or 'tens of thousands', or 'showing 20 of about 23123123 results'. Well, now you see why. Welcome to the world of noSQL

(although, frankly, counts with filters are bad in the sql land as well).

It's not a solution, but a workaround, but it's common:

- make a query;
- try to load 1001 entities, even if you only wish to show 20;
- if it works, show a "more than 1000"; if you get less than 1001, show the exact number.

This can be pretty effective and users do not seem to mind (nor notice).

Comment: some users notice: see randall's explanation of how inaccurate those google estimates really are... http://blog.xkcd.com/2011/02/04/trochee-chart/

Comment: when estimating search results, this might be acceptable.  but when enumerating items in a catalog, having an accurate count is a reasonable expectation.

Comment: @Peter: I know some people notice. I certainly do! But Bigtable does not work by magic (almost, but not quite). And - I am not an expert here - using it for generic queries / complicated filters / limiting / sorting/ad hoc aggregations is exactly it's weakest scenario.

Comment: OK.  I just wanted to emphasize that just because google gets away with it doesn't mean it isn't worth trying to make it work :)